# How do I compare a fetched value in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database named `"login"` and `"valid_stuid"(valid student id)`. `"valid stuid"` has two rows which are `"stu_id"` and `"status"`, let's say for now 1 column is available in the table `"valid stuid"` which are `"123"` under the `"stu_id"` row and `"open"` under the `"status"` row. I created a php script to register a user with a student id, username, password, first name and last name. So far I have successfully inputted them onto the database but I'm struggling in selecting the status from the `valid_stuid` table.

My code goes something like:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
if(!empty($_POST['stuid']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) &&       !empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname'])) {
$stuid=$_POST['stuid'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");

$stuidcheck="SELECT status FROM valid_stuid WHERE id='".$stuid."'";
        if($stuidcheck == "used")
            {
            echo "Student ID is registered to another account!";
            }
        else{
            $sql1="INSERT INTO login(stu_id,username,password,first_name,last_name) VALUES('$stuid','$user','$pass','$fname','$lname')";
            mysql_query($sql1);
            $sql2="INSERT INTO valid_stuid(stu_id,status) VALUES('$stuid','used')";
            mysql_query($sql2);
            }
} else {
echo "Please fill up all fields";
}
}
?>
```

I think I failed miserably in comparing the value of the `$stuidcheck` and got the idea of comparing like this from other languages. I also plan on using modify to change the status from `"open"` to `"used"` but I'll try to do it after I finish this.

Comment: `$stuidcheck` is a string. Execute a `$stuidcheck` query first.

Comment: it seems you are comparing an array with string use $stuidcheck['status'] instead of `$stuidcheck`

Comment: @u_mulder, I actually don't know how to query a select so I assumed  the query from insert would work but I removed it since it isn't working anyway. I'll try researching on how to properly query a select statement. Thank you

Comment: @AVM, That makes sense, but I'm still left with an unquery'd statement. But thanks a lot! If I ever successfully queried this select statement, my next problem would be the comparison but you answered it so thanks!

Comment: @Carl Dun: you query a select just as you'd do with any other SQL query, with the `mysql_query()` instruction. The difference is in whether the query will return something to you; if it does, as in "SELECT" queries, you'll have to capture that result in a variable ($result) and extract whatever you want from it.

Comment: Oh, and another thing: please stop using the `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli_`instead (read the docs for more details).

Comment: @PaulJ, Thank you that's what I am currently studying as of typing this. But your additional information gave me a broader understanding in query'ing a select. Oh and thanks also for the mysql advice, you've actually helped me in a lot of stuff not only for my main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually perform the query against your DB:

```
$stuidcheck="SELECT status FROM valid_stuid WHERE id='".$stuid."'";
    if($stuidcheck == "used")
```

All this does is to give the string `$stuidcheck` the value "SELECT...", but you need to do something like:

```
$result=mysql_query($stuidcheck);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['status'] == "used")
```

Or something like that (my PHP is a bit rusty, but you'll find thousands of code examples for this).

Comment: Thank you so much, although the code didn't work, I get to see where my problem is so I could effectively research on how to do it properly. I just started php a week ago and for this week I decided how to integrate sql and php so I'm still struggling but you've helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: OMG I'm so dumb, this code DID WORK! it was my fault! I used mysqli_error to determine the problem and it turns out I put id instead of stu_id after the WHERE. Thank you so much PaulJ!